# Get shapefile to display on the canvas

Tags: qgis, shapefile, display

Please see below for the **requested edits.**

I created a shapefile from a .cvs rendering of a spreadsheet. I have loaded it into my project and it shows up in the layers list to the left of the canvas. It does not however display the points on the canvas although the other layers do show. If I zoom to the layer it appears on the canvas but the other layers don't. The relative locations of the points look good.

How can I get it to display along with the other layers?

**Requested edits:**
GIS software: QGIS version 3.30.0-'s-Hertogenbosch

From the Copy Coordinates function for my layer I get: Map ESPG: 2230 NAD 83 California Zone 6 (ftUS)(-117.032850E,32.738261N)
EPSG:4326 WGS84 (25.945516752N,-136.179136677E).

For another layer which is working "normally" called ("Municipal Boundaries") I get:Map ESPG: 2230 NAD 83 California Zone 6 (ftUS) 6320695E,1847641N)
ESPG:4326 WGS84 (32.73370,-117.03383)

The other layers in my project are as for "Municipal Boundaries."

I don't recall what CRS I specified.

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to specify the GIS software in use. You should also indicate the geometry type on your table.

Comment: And also include a sample coordinate pair and what projection you specified (if any) when you added it to your project.

Comment: Maybe you've got the X and Y coordinates mixed up. Try adding the delimited text layer again, swapping them

Comment: Be sure to specify the correct CRS of your coordinates when loading the layer. Otherwise, it will be misplaced

Answer (score 0):

###### From your question

> Map ESPG: 2230 NAD 83 California Zone 6 (ftUS)(-117.032850E,32.738261N) EPSG:4326 WGS84 (25.945516752N,-136.179136677E).
>
> Map ESPG: 2230 NAD 83 California Zone 6 (ftUS) 6320695E,1847641N) ESPG:4326 WGS84 (32.73370,-117.03383)

###### Problem

There is a huge disparity between these locations in the EPSG: 2230 coordinate system.

[image]

###### Reason

It looks like your 'problem layer' has EPSG:4326 coordinates, and not projected coordinates.

###### Solution

Try assigning EPSG:4326 as the layer's CRS and it should be projected by QGIS ['on-the-fly'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#basic-fa-on-the-fly-reprojection) to the right location.

Right-click the layer name > Layer CRS > Set to EPSG:4326